# How to call argument of a function from another function as variable in Python

Tags: python

```
def func1(arg1,arg2):
    do_something

def func2(arg3)
    print arg1
    print arg2
```

How can I call argument of a function from another function in Python as illustrated above ?

Comment: you wanna print what? values of `arg1`,`arg2` or the variable names?

Comment: question is weird.. please edit it or remove it

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this. It would not make much sense after all. Right now those functions don't even call each other somehow...

But even if `func1` called `func2` it would not be possible without some extremely nasty hack involving the call stack.

So, if you want to access arguments from `func1` in `func2` you need to pass them as arguments to `func2` when calling it.

---

In case anyone is curious, here is code using the `inspect` module to get a dict of the arguments passed to the caller function. **Do not use this in any production code!**

```
import inspect

def get_caller_args():
    frame = inspect.stack()[2][0]
    argspec = inspect.getargvalues(frame)
    return {x: argspec.locals[x] for x in argspec.args}

def func1(arg1, arg2):
    test = 'xxx'
    func2('moo')

def func2(arg):
    print "caller's args: %r" % get_caller_args()

func1('foo', 'bar')
```

**Output:**

> caller's args: {'arg1': 'foo', 'arg2': 'bar'}

Note that this code has a major caveat which cannot be avoided: If `func1` changes the value of `arg1` or `arg2` that new value will be returned instead of the initial one.

Comment: Can't do *what*? Currently I don't even understand the question...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Might be because his questions makes no sense at all. Anyway, I edited my answer according to my guess on what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps you, as the question is quite unclear, but you can create a closure by nesting function definitions like this:

```
def func1(arg1,arg2):
  do_something()

  def func2(arg3)
    print arg1
    print arg2

  return func2

the_func2 = func1(foo, bar)
do_something_else()
the_func2(42) # prints foo and bar
```